# Accurate summation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm writing a program which takes numerical x and y data as a numpy array, and then integrates it (numerically) over a region of x. I did this and now I'm starting to wonder about precision.

I noticed that `math.fsum()` corrects for certain errors in ways that `sum()` does not - does `numpy.sum` also make these corrections?

If I write `sum = numpy.sum(array)`, or something similar, is the result (sum) as accurate as it can be? I am summing thousands of data points which are themselves the product of several operations, so small errors could accumulate. I'm not versed enough in Python to know if there's some more accurate math module I should be using when accuracy to many decimal places is important.

Answer (score 1):

No, `numpy.sum` *doesn't* do the corrections `math.fsum` does. It uses [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation), which isn't as good as the techniques `math.fsum` uses, although I'm not sure it's so much worse.

Comment: It's worse if there are lots of small summands, which is the OP's exact use case. `math.fsum` is definitely advised.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few numerical integration implementations in scipy, numpy libs if you want better methods

some you can apply to an array of point (pairs):
[numpy.trapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)

or you can use interpolation, integrate the spline fit: [scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.integral](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.integral.html)

if you have a function:  [scipy.integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)